# Client cant see the Updated dynamic content

Tags: php, cache

I have came across an issue... whenever I upload new content to the site.. and i send the link to the client.. He can not view the changes instead what he see is the previously updated content. Looks like there is some caching issue.. but i have never seen dynamic content being cached.

Even I have to clear my cache on Safari to view the dynamic changes..

I am using a theme Village . Not sure if that is the theme issue.. Is there any solution to this which i may try rather than waiting for the Theme developer to respond?

I use the following code to make sure that the updated content is loaded everytime the page load.

`<?php
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0');
header ('Pragma: no-cache');
?>`

But will it Re-load everything including Js and css files?? If that is the case, then i shouldn't be using this technique?

Thanks,

Nasir

Comment: Not gonna post this as answer because it's a long shot, but I've seen something similar related to a host company, don't remember which...

Comment: Probably 1&1 they seem to hate WP users with a burning passion.

Comment: i use Bluehost... 
Yes 1&1 hates WP users :D

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that's definitely a caching issue. The code you have there should handle it but you can't really guarantee anything.

Do you have a caching plugin installed? If so try disabling that.

Also in your `wp-config.php` file see if you have this `define('WP_CACHE', true);` if so change it to false. If it isn't there add it but make that false.

That's really all, in my experience, you can do from our end unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, But will the code which i used will reload everything including CSS nad JS resources???
If that is the case i wont be using it because i dont want a bad user experience by loading all the resources on everypage....

Also there was no `define('WP_CACHE', true);` so i have added this code with False Value...

Comment: Yeah, from my understanding providing the page respects those calls it essentially tells the server to load the page ignoring any cache and expires any cache that it does have as a backup. So yes, it will force everything to load again upon every page request providing that code is honoured by the browser.

Comment: ok, is there any way to tell the browser to re-load only the dynamic content and do caching process with .js and .css ?
may be we should do something with .htaccess ??

Comment: Not that I am aware of sorry.